# Is it possible to upload my code from github into my AWS account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

I have put my basic html code onto my github repo. I was wondering if I can push the code from github onto AWS, which will then allow me to monitor its health and the usage of it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve this, you can use AWS CodeDeploy -http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/github-integ-tutorial.html - where I guess you have completed step 1,2 and 3.

Step 6 is handy too, as it explains how you can monitor your deployment and monitor its state.

Answer (score 0):

AWS has the CodeDeploy service, it coordinates application deployments to Amazon EC2 instances, on-premises instances, or both. You do not need to make changes to your existing code to use AWS CodeDeploy. You can use AWS CodeDeploy to control the pace of deployment across Amazon EC2 instances and to define the actions to be taken at each stage.

Here is the [explanation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/github-integ.html) and a [tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/github-integ-tutorial.html) that shows you how to deploy an application hosted in GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

You could use CodeDeploy, Elastic Beanstalk, login to your EC2 server and do a `git clone` command, among many options.

Your question is a bit vague and open-ended to provide a very concrete answer. Are you wanting to install your app on a server? What sort of web server are you using to serve it currently? Do you just have a static website in GitHub that you want to install on S3? Do you want the website on AWS to be automatically updated when you do a `git push` or are you just asking a general question about setting up a website on AWS?